# How to assign random values from an array to the items from another array in JavaScript (assign an array of names to an array of week days)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, random

I have this array of week days:

```
var weekDays = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
```

And another array of employees:

```
var empl = ["Bill Smith", "Bob Brown", "Megan Stallion", "Seth Evermann", "Kelly Swartz", "Mike Belltooth"];
```

The employees from the 2nd array have to work on one of the days from the 1st array, e.g. Mon: Bill Smith etc.

What I have so far is this:

```
var weekDays = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]; 

for (var i = 0; i < weekDays.length; i++){
var empl = ["Bill Smith", "Bob Brown", "Megan Taylor", "Seth Evermann", 
"Kelly Swartz", "Mike Woods"];

console.log( "Day: " + i + ";" + " Shift: " + 
empl[Math.floor(Math.random()*empl.length)] + ";" );
}
```

Which resulted in something like this:

```
Day: 0; Shift: Megan Taylor;
Day: 1; Shift: Mike Woods;
Day: 2; Shift: Seth Evermann;
Day: 3; Shift: Bill Smith;
Day: 4; Shift: Bill Smith;
Day: 5; Shift: Bill Smith;
```

But I need it to be Day: Mon, Day: Tue, Day: Wed etc. instead of Day: 0, Day: 1 etc.

Also I would like each name only to be used once so every person had to work only on one of those days.

The result should be something like this:

```
Day: Mon; Shift: Bob Brown; 
Day: Tue; Shift: Megan Taylor; 
Day: Wed; Shift: Bill Smith; 
...
```

I would really appreciate any help on this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Use `for of` syntax and `splice`:

```js
var weekDays = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]; 
var empl = ["Bill Smith", "Bob Brown", "Megan Taylor", "Seth Evermann", "Kelly Swartz", "Mike Woods"];

for (var i of weekDays){
  console.log( 
    "Day: " + i + ";" + " Shift: " + 
    empl.splice(Math.random()*empl.length|0, 1) + ";" 
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing one piece of code.

Yours:

```
console.log( "Day: " + i + ";" + " Shift: " + empl[Math.floor(Math.random()*empl.length)] + ";" );
```

Updated:

```
console.log( "Day: " + weekDays[i] + ";" + " Shift: " + empl[Math.floor(Math.random()*empl.length)] + ";" );
```